# How to convert UPDATE outer apply to Update Left Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running this query on sql 2008 but my client need this to run on sql 2000.
can someone help me convert this query to sql 2000?

```
Update cust set Balance = dv.balance 
From (SELECT hb.Balance,dv.custnum FROM [#custnumtbl] as dv 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Balance,custnum FROM CLedger b 
WHERE b.CustNum = dv.custnum ORDER BY Pdate DESC) as hb) as dv 
where cust.CustNum = dv.custnum
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to the following correlated subquery:

```
Update cust
    set Balance = (SELECT TOP 1 cl.Balance
                   FROM [#custnumtbl] dv JOIN
                        Cledger b
                        ON b.CustNum = dv.custnum
                   WHERE dv.custnum = cust.CustNum
                   ORDER BY Pdate DESC
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL2000 does not support `ORDER` inside the view

```
UPDATE cust SET Balance = cl.Balance
FROM 
    cust 
    INNER JOIN [#custnumtbl] tmp ON cust.CustNum = tmp.CustNum
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLedger cl ON 
        cl.CustNum = cust.CustNum 
        AND PDate = (SELECT MAX(PDate) FROM CLedger WHERE CustNum = cl.CustNum)
```